# Using find() on an array of protocol types

Tags: arrays, swift

Whenever I create an array of Protocol Types, how would I obtain the index of an object in that array? I've tried the below:

```
protocol aProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

class aClass: aProtocol, Equatable {
    var aProperty = "test"

    func doSomething() {

    }
}

func == (lhs: aClass, rhs: aClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.aProperty == rhs.aProperty
}

var testArray = aProtocol[]()
let testObject = aClass()

testArray += testObject

find(testArray, testObject)
```

In this case I get a "Cannot convert the expression's type '$T4?' to type 'aClass'" error.

Looking at find()'s method signature we find that the element should implement Equatable (which is why I overload the == operator above):

```
func find<C : Collection where C.GeneratorType.Element : Equatable>(domain: C, value: C.GeneratorType.Element) -> C.IndexType?
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what I'm doing wrong or if this scenario is even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If `find()` expects its first argument to have elements that are `Equatable` and its second argument to be `Equatable` too, then invoking `find()` on an array of non-Equatable `aProtocol` elements won't compile.

To fix, change to

```
protocol aProtocol : Equatable { ... }
```

and then implement the `Equatable` protocol for your `aClass` definition.

Comment: That won't actually work for an array declared as `asProtocol[]` because then the equality operator must be `func == (lhs: asProtocol, rhs: asProtocol) -> Bool`. The real problem is that if you have two classes, e.g. `classA` and `classB`, both conforming to `aProtocol` and both conforming to `Equatable`, you can't still compare an instance of `classA` with instances of `classB`. So, you have to implement equality based on the protocol, not specific equality for every class that implements it.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm not in front of a Mac at the moment, so I can't verify this suggestion.]

You overload the == function, but you don't mark aClass as conforming to the Equatable protocol.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nisroc. I did have aClass marked as conforming to the Equatable protocol, so I must have forgotten to add it to the post after making some changes in my playground. I did double-check that the error still occurs even with the protocol. Editing the post now.